Add prefix to crosstool-ng sysroot binaries in `sysroot/usr/`
I am building a cross-native toolchain with crosstool-ng: build=x86_64, host=target=arm.
I  need this new toolchain to include a different glibc than the one already installed to the system at /.
On the host device, the new toolchain will live inside a user directory $HOST_SYSROOT and I can't touch the rest of the system.
The ct-ng config I have produces an almost entirely working toolchain with one exception: the objects in [toolchain dir]/[host arch]/sysroot/usr/ reference / instead of /$HOST_SYSROOT/[...].
For example the binaries in sysroot/usr/bin (like, say, locale) all use the linker at /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 instead of $HOST_SYSROOT/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3.
How do I fix this?
Using patchelf to add the right rpath and interpreter to the binaries does not fix things since other parts of the binary reference more root directories. It is as though one is intended to merge the sysroot/ dir with /, which I cannot do on my system.
I believe some part of my ct-ng config must be missing autoconf flag --prefix=$HOST_SYSROOT flag, or CFLAG --sysroot=$HOST_SYSROOT.
I thought it was glibc but adding this prefix causes the build to fail at Installing final gcc compiler for build.
